# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3306

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I'm trying to create a log system with MySQL and Node.JS. But I'm getting the error you see below, I'm still actively looking for a solution, but I couldn't find it. And I decided to ask you.

.env

```
DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1
DB_USER = newuser
DB_PASSWORD = password123#
DB_DATABASE = userDB
DB_PORT = 3306

PORT = 3000
```

Node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const mysql = require('mysql');

require('dotenv').config({path: './dbInfo.env'})

const db = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT
})

db.getConnection( (err, connection) => {

    if (err) throw (err)
    console.log("DB connected succesful:" + connection.threadId)

})

const port = process.env.DB_PORT

app.listen(port, 
    () => console.log('Server started on port ${port}...'))

console.log(process.env.DB_PASSWORD)
```

Comment: You are trying to start you node.js/express app on port 3306. That is already used by MySQL. Choose a different port. `const port = process.env.DB_PORT`

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Port 3306 is already used. 3306 is the MySQL standard port, so most likely your MySQL instance is already running which you would want.

You can only have one service running behind a port. That's the purpose of ports to direct traffic to the process that can deal with that traffic or expects that traffic.

To resolve the issue use `const port = process.env.PORT` instead of `const port = process.env.DB_PORT`. Your Express server then runs on port `3000` and your MySQL server on port `3306`.

FYI: You should specify some default values (or errors) in case the environment variables are not set. You might have set them here with your `.env` file both you might wanna run the server in another environment some day and you'll forget to configure something and wonder why your server is crashing.

One quick and easy solution that will do for starters could be to use logical *OR* (`||`). This will set the port set in the environment variables or the default value of `3000`.

```js
// Mocking process.env
const process = { env: {}} 
// process.env.PORT is not defined here so the default value will be used
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
console.log(`Port: ${port}`)
```

You might also be interested in the [*dotenv* npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: I read what you said and thanks for your answer! After what you said I deleted port 3000 and started the code that way, it worked fine and then I reinstated the code to find where the problem was, but for some reason the problem solved itself. Even if I run it as in the post I opened, it does not give an error. As the most likely possibility, I think the VS Code is faulty.